# War deployment on Tomcat takes ages

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I have a Grails application, built to a war file (~30mb). When I attempt to deploy the war file on Tomcat 6 via the application manager, it takes upwards of 10 minutes to deploy, or hangs indefinitely. When it hangs I can restart Tomcat and the app is usually deployed, however sometimes I have to repeat the process. I've also noticed that during deployment, the Java process maxes out the CPU and the RAM is at ~10-15%.

I'm fairly new to Java, so I don't know if this is normal, but I can't imagine how it could be. Is there something I can do to make this run smoother/faster? Is there a better way to deploy than Tomcat's app manager?

Comment: Check tomcat logs (tomcat/logs/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I upload the WAR to my home directory, cd to /usr/local/tomcat, then run the following commands:

```
bin/shutdown.sh
rm webapps/ROOT.war
rm -rf webapps/ROOT
cp ~/ROOT.war webapps
bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: These seems to be the way to go. Deploying directly from the webapps folder only took a minute or two. Re: hot deployment, I found the system a little sluggish after a hot deployment, so the shutdown, deploy, startup strategy seems best. Thanks!

Comment: Another note on hot deployment, with 100% CPU usage, the live app is completely incapacitated anyway, so there's little benefit to keeping Tomcat online during the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely check the Tomcat logs for any errors/warnings.

You probably have some expensive/sensitive code logic in one of the `ServletContextListener`s. They are usually initialized during startup. If so, then I would debug/profile it for any performance matters/leaks.

Answer (score 2):

As noted I would copy the war to the webapps folder and let tomcat do the deployment, its also quicker saving you time.

Both Tomcat and Jetty will support a hot deploy. They simply monitor the deploy directory for changes, so you can just copy the .war file into that directory, and the server will undeploy/redeploy.

If using a remote server check the lag is not the time take to upload the war to a remote server over the network.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use application manager. My way is to upload it somewhere out of the webapps directory and then copy it to webapps directory. Takes a lot less of deplyoment time.

Comment: Will it not collide if application server starts loading your webapp before all files (relevant class per se) have been copied?

Comment: I copy war file, not extracted files.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always that you have sufficient access rights to manually put files in the `webapps` folder -- you are supposed to use the Tomcat Application Manager for `.war` file deployment, and need to make it work.

For me, it has been common that the process of uploading of a `.war` file to the server cannot complete; it gets stuck somewhere in the middle and the file is only partially uploaded to the server, no matter how many times I retry. In such situations, I have found it worthwhile to try another browser. For instance, I've found myself stuck using Google Chrome but once I switched to a freshly started Firefox browser, things worked out.

Comment: superuser privileges for deployment account can make miracles for you. direct copy to filesystem is waaay faster than using Tomcat administrative interface

Answer (score 0):

This may be relate to this [BUG of JDK](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093)

I readed [this article, Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean) and resolved my problem.

Try to resolve it by **replacing**

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

with

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

in `$JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security`